# Help NDSolve with PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I'm not an expert user with mathematica, but I have a homework that I need to solve this following PDE:

$\frac{\partial u_{z}}{\partial t} = \nu \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r \frac{\partial u_{z}}{\partial r}) - \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial z} $

with these following conditions:

[image: s]

[image]

[image]

The parameters are:

In Mathematica, I'm using this code:

```
u0 = 0; R0 = 0; R = 0.425; v = 0.09; rho = 1; w = 6*Pi; dPdL = 1; dPdZ = -dPdL*Cos[w*t]; tF = 100;

PDE = D[u[t, r], t] == v*1/r*D[r*D[u[t, r], r], r] - 1/rho*dPdZ;

CI = u[t, r] == u0 /. t -> 0; BC1 = D[u[t, r], r] == 0 /. r -> 0; BC2 = u[t, r] == 0 /. r -> R;

rDomain = {r, 0, R}; tDomain = {t, 0, tF};

uSol = NDSolve[{EDP, CI, BC1, BC2}, u[t, r], rDomain, tDomain];
```

But, in return, the softwares gives:

[image]

Does anyone can give me tips to solve this error?

Note: u0 wasn't given in the command, so I suposed u0 -> 0.

Comment: With `r` in the denominator, the PDE will blow up at `r = 0`.  The easiest to try is to change your `r=0` to `r=`some very small positive number in both your BC1 and your rDomain.  Also fix your EDP typo in your `NDSolve` command.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bill Watts suggested, you could do something like this:

```
u0 = 0; R0 = 0; R = 0.425;
Rsmall = R/1000000;
v = 0.09; rho = 1; w = 6*Pi; dPdL = 1; dPdZ = -dPdL*Cos[w*t]; tF = 1;
PDE = D[u[t, r], t] == v*1/r*D[r*D[u[t, r], r], r] - 1/rho*dPdZ;
CI = u[0, r] == u0; BC1 = D[u[t, r], r] == 0 /. r -> Rsmall; BC2 = 
 u[t, r] == 0 /. r -> R;
rDomain = {r, Rsmall, R}; tDomain = {t, 0, tF};
ufun = NDSolveValue[{PDE, CI, BC1, BC2}, u , tDomain, rDomain];
frames = Plot[ufun[#, r], rDomain, PlotRange -> {-0.065, 0.065}] & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, tF, 100];
ListAnimate@frames
```

[image]